# Two-norm function norm of interpolation

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, numerical-methods, normed-spaces

[image]

I am attempting to calculate the two-norm of this function $f_k(x)$.

$$ \|f_k\|_2 = \left( \int_0^1 f_k(x)^{2} dx \right)^{1/2} $$

The answer is listed as $$ \sqrt{2/3} $$

However, I'm not getting the same value when I attempt the solution. I'm getting the area as $1/k^2$ and then 1 using the definite integral. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The "area" would actually be $\int\limits_{0}^{1}{|f_k(x)|\text{ d}x}$, which is not what you're trying to calculate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_{0}^{1}f_k(x)^2\,dx = 2\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{k^2}}(k-k^3 x)^2\,dx = 2k^2 \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{k^2}}(1-k^2 x)^2\,dx = 2\int_{0}^{1}(1-x)^2\,dx,$$

hence:
$$ \| f_k \|_2 = \sqrt{\int_{0}^{1}f_k(x)^2\,dx} = \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}.$$

Comment: Thanks. May I ask where the $(k - k^{3}x)$ part comes from?

Comment: @stevetronix: it is the equation of a line that goes through $(0,k)$ and $\left(\frac{1}{k^2},0\right)$.